# How does eth-lighwallet store its saved passwords

Tags: ethereum

I am interested in how eth-lightwallet stores user passwords to generate keys if they are for example pre deterministic where you don't need to store them somewhere or if they are encrypted and stored in some kind of location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an `eth-lightwallet` you have an instance that you can use. the library doesn't handle longterm storage of wallets. you have to use a storage library storj.js or serialize the wallet and make users download it as a JSON-file and upload it later.